# Upper bound on the $2$-norm of inverse of a triangular Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, singular-values, spectral-norm

Consider a lower triangular square Toeplitz matrix

\begin{align}
T_n = \begin{bmatrix}
t_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
t_2 & t_1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
t_n & t_{n-1} & t_{n-2} & \dots & t_1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Matrix $T_n$ satisfies two conditions:

1. $t_1 > 0$
2. $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n t_i^2 = c \leq 1$

Is it possible to find a lower bound on the smallest singular value of $T_n$ (or equivalently, an upper bound on $\|T_n^{-1}\|_2^2$) in terms of $t_1, c$ and $n$?

---

Update: Based on the comment below, one can write $T^{-1}_n$ which is also triangular and Toeplitz. One upper bound on the 2-norm of Toeplitz is the following

$$\|T_n\|_2^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n t_i^2.$$

Is it possible to write a nice upper bound for the elements of $T^{-1}_n$?

Comment: It's pretty easy to get a direct formula for $T_n^{-1}$ in terms of the $t_i$, which means that the problem comes down to getting a nice bound on the largest singular value of $T_n$ in terms of its entries. That said, I'm not sure that there's a nice way to get such a bound.